# Can you use the turtle module and the pygame module?

Tags: python, pygame

I have coded a simple game in python using the turtle module but can't work out how to add background music without pygame.

Comment: You can try using the winsound module of you're on Windows.

Comment: I am on a mac, but thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out

```
pip install playsound
```

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound('audio.mp3')
```

Hope this works

Comment: what do you mean by pip install playsound. sorry I have to do a uni assignment and am new to code

Comment: do `pip install playsound` in your terminal since you are a macos user

Comment: what command are you taking about, may you explain?

Comment: when i type pip install playsound, it says-                     bash: pip: command not found

Comment: try this first `easy_install pip` or `sudo easy_install pip` then do `pip install playsound`

Comment: hmm the first one gave me the same error and then I tried the second one and it said it installed. However, in python again it says no module found.

Comment: thats weird because its working perfectly fine for me

Comment: perhaps you need to use `pip3 install playsound`